# Problem with connection Pony ORM to PostgreSQL

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, ponyorm

Trying to connect to the PostgreSQL DB with Pony ORM.
Running script from venv with installed packages **pony** and **psycopg2**.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Sx2.png)
But still have exception:

```
D:\***\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/***/models.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\***\venv\lib\site-packages\pony\orm\dbproviders\postgres.py", line 9, in <module>
    import psycopg2
  File "D:\***\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: Не найден указанный модуль.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\***\venv\lib\site-packages\pony\orm\dbproviders\postgres.py", line 12, in <module>
    from psycopg2cffi import compat
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2cffi'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/***/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    db.bind(**DB_CONFIG)
  File "D:\***\venv\lib\site-packages\pony\orm\core.py", line 769, in bind
    self._bind(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\***\venv\lib\site-packages\pony\orm\core.py", line 788, in _bind
    provider_module = import_module('pony.orm.dbproviders.' + provider)
  File "D:\***\venv\lib\site-packages\pony\utils\utils.py", line 219, in import_module
    mod = __import__(name)
  File "D:\***\venv\lib\site-packages\pony\orm\dbproviders\postgres.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise ImportError('In order to use PonyORM with PostgreSQL please install psycopg2 or psycopg2cffi')
ImportError: In order to use PonyORM with PostgreSQL please install psycopg2 or psycopg2cffi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing psycopg2 again, but this time try to take advantage of the pre-compiled binary:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi

Comment: @sdmnt, Did you try it with a new virtual environment? If so, was the error message the same or different?